# PHP jQuery AJAX with MySQL results pagination

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am facing a weird problem. I have made a page which shows MySQL results using jQuery AJAX function. The results are displayed as 12 in each page hence there are multiple pages hence the pagination.

The problem is that when I click on page 2 or 'Next page' it goes to page 2 but when I click page 3 or 'next page' again instead of going to page 3 it goes back to page 1. Same thing happens when I click on page 2 from page 3. It always returns to page 1 before going to any other page. The reason is that the

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['page'])) {
    $page = $_REQUEST['page'];
}
else{
    $page = 1;
}
```

is returning false hence it is setting the page back to 1 every time before going to a third page except when its on the first page.

This is the jQuery AJAX function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".pagination a").on( "click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".loading-div").show(); //show loading element
    var page = $(this).attr("data-page"); //get page number from link
    $("#container").remove();
    $("#content").load("fetch_page.php",{"page":page}, function(){ 
        $(".loading-div").hide(); // hide loading element
    });
 });
</script>
```

Also, I have an image zooming function that when clicked on an image it shows as a modal box type window. Even that works only on page 1 and not on any other page. It works even if I load page 2 and click page 1 again. I notice that when I click on page 1 the page loads as if it's not loading through AJAX but loading the entire page itself because it loads the page on top. Whereas other pages load as expected using AJAX.

It's weird and I don't understand why this is happening although I have checked the pagination codes and it clearly does not have any URL at all in the `href` attribute.

Comment: Try doing an `alert(page)` after you set `var page` to see if the problem is there. If you are getting unexpected values here, perhaps your `data-page` attributes are wrong in the clickable page numbers.

Comment: thanks. I think i might just have found the problem. It is that the script is not loading with the DOM reload so it might be causing the problem. I'll try and fix it. However, I'm still clueless about the image problem. can you please helpp?

Comment: Do you get any JS errors in your console when you're on page 2? Can we see your code that sets up the zoom?

Comment: looked at everything in the console and firebug. Absolutely no JS errors. The JS file/css and php file all have loaded without any errors. The magnifying glass appears too when I am on page two which means the CSS had loaded perfectly. and the DOM elements are perfectly loaded via AJAX

Comment: Hey. I just figured it out.. I placed the JS script inside the file that gets loaded via AJAX and it works now. Which means that I need to load the JS file each and every time the DOM loads. So basically all JS must be loaded every time there is a new AJAX request?? Maybe because browser stores JS info in the memory and once the DOM loads again the memory address changes?? Don't know really.

Comment: I don't know which JavaScript script you're referring to - the event initialisation or the handler? - but no, you don't need to include these in the AJAX payload. Maybe you are overwriting the pagination links when you render a new page, which disconnects the events you have set up? If so, look at "delegated events" [in the `on()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: I was taking about the same js that I have quoted above in the question. I placed it in the fetch_page.php document which loads on Ajax request and now it works perfectly. Before it was placed on the main page.

Comment: Righto. See my above comment for how to fix that, and what the likely problem is. I think your AJAX op overwrites the HTML, destroys the handlers, adds a new script, which in turn re-attaches the handles. It works, but it's not ideal.

Comment: Genius!! As you said I delegated and it works!! this is my new code in the answer

Comment: If I could ask you just one more thing? on my main page I have this fetch_page.php loading when the page loads. This shows all the MySQL content. Now I also have a search bar and 3 other links which are sub categories of contents that load from the database. Now Is there a way to load everything in to one single fetch_page.php? I have currently 4 different pages for each 3 sub categories and 1 for the search which load using ajax in to the same main page DOM element. Thanks for the help

Comment: Sure. Your response is JSON, so just populate the response with the page contents in different keys (e.g. `page1`, `page2` etc). You will need to load them manually, rather than using `load()`. If you need more detail than this, please ask a new question.

Comment: @PankajLohia it will be nice if you can post html also and the complete answer for newbie to follow, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works with delegation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content" ).load( "fetch_page.php");

$("#content").on( "click", ".pagination a", function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".loading-div").show(); //show loading element
    var page = $(this).attr("data-page"); //get page number from link
    $("#content").load("fetch_page.php",{"page":page}, function(){ //get content
        $(".loading-div").hide(); //hide loading element
    });
  });
});
```